# How to duplicate nested dictionaries without aliasing?

Tags: python, dictionary, alias

In python I am looking to create nested dictionaries for a text parsing application.  The data structure I have right now uses a dictionary to reference two sub dictionaries, and then each of those sub dictionaries has multiple subdictionaries, and then those subdictionaries have values.  All of the innermost dictionaries have the same fields.

```
# innermost dictionary 
specificSensorInfo = {
    "value":None,
    "status":None
}

# middle dictionaries
board1_sensors = {
    13  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"AUX +3.3V Vol"
    14  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"MCU_Temperature" 
    15  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"AUX +3.3V Temp"  
}

board2_sensors = {
    13  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"AUX +3.3V Vol"
    14  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"MCU_Temperature" 
    15  :   specificSensorInfo,   #"AUX +3.3V Temp"  
}

#outermost dictionary
all_sensor_info = {'B1':board1_sensors,
                   'B2':board2_sensors}
```

I am going to parse a text file and then set the values of the dictionary based on what is parsed. I expect to fill out the data fields like this:

```
all_sensor_info['B1'][13]['value'] = 10
all_sensor_info['B2'][14]['status'] = 'OK'
```

The problem I am finding is that when I change a value in one of the innermost dictionaries, it changes that value across all of the data.  So in the above example every *specificSensorInfo* dictionary would show *{10, 'OK'}*.  This is because all the dictionaries reference the same object, I think.

How can I accomplish what I'm looking for?  Do I need to create a class and set attributes? I thought using dictionaries would be easier to use than classes so I can use the [] operator instead of the dot operator.

Comment: If you want separate dictionaries then look at deep copying using `copy.deepcopy` https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy

Answer (score 1):

Don't reference the *same* dictionary 6 times, as then indeed a mutation of that *single* dictionary will be seen through all properties that have that reference.

Instead, create new dictionaries using the `dict` constructor:

```
# middle dictionaries
board1_sensors = {
    13  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"AUX +3.3V Vol"
    14  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"MCU_Temperature" 
    15  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"AUX +3.3V Temp"  
}

board2_sensors = {
    13  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"AUX +3.3V Vol"
    14  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"MCU_Temperature" 
    15  :   dict(specificSensorInfo),   #"AUX +3.3V Temp"  
}
```

Alternatively, you can create the structure in nested loops, and -- why not -- using dictionary comprehension:

```
all_sensor_info = { 
    # middle dictionaries
    code: {
        # innermost dictionaries
        id: {
            "value":None,
            "status":None
        }
        for id in (13, 14, 15)
    } 
    for code in ('B1', 'B2')
}
```

Comment: will this perform a deep copy or shallow copy?

Comment: This is a shallow copy, which is all that is needed here, since the Asker indicated that the third level has (immutable) values.

Comment: yep, i agree that it's fine for op. was just wondering